# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger in JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss

I have been creating a REST Web Service, which would intercept requests from a client and query an employee table in the MySQL database via Hibernate and return the retrieved rows to the client. The web service calls a class in another project which solely deals with interacting with the MySQL database using Hibernate. For enabling it, I'm using Maven to build the database project into a jar which I'm then placing in the WEB-INF folder of the web service. The project structures of all three projects are attached herewith.

I had bundled all the jars required by Hibernate in the Maven dependencies. As a result, when I tried to call the deployed service from the client, it threw an exception in JBoss saying:

`"Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml Warning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader Warning: Exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader"`

After browsing through a lot of solutions all pointing that this is due to me bundling the Hibernate jars in the deployed war, I removed the dependencies from Maven and instead, placed the jars in the lib folder of the JBoss server to which I am deploying my application. However, now, a new exception has cropped up, and I'm pasting the entire stacktrace here.

```
14:10:46,788 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
14:10:46,789 SEVERE [ContainerResponse] The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.employee.database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:31)
at com.employee.database.AccessEmployeeDatabase.getEmployeeList(AccessEmployeeDatabase.java:14)
at com.alumnus.employeemanagement.EmployeeManagement.fetchEmployeeDetailsFromDB(EmployeeManagement.java:48)
at com.alumnus.employeemanagement.EmployeeManagement.getEmployeeDetails(EmployeeManagement.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:192)
at com.employee.database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:21)
... 43 more
14:10:46,791 ERROR [[Employee REST Service]] Servlet.service() for servlet Employee REST Service threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:192)
at com.employee.database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:21)
at com.employee.database.AccessEmployeeDatabase.getEmployeeList(AccessEmployeeDatabase.java:14)
at com.alumnus.employeemanagement.EmployeeManagement.fetchEmployeeDetailsFromDB(EmployeeManagement.java:48)
at com.alumnus.employeemanagement.EmployeeManagement.getEmployeeDetails(EmployeeManagement.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have extensively searched for this exception as well, and the only solution I can find is that there may be two different logging jars on the classpath, and I would have to remove one of them. I found that JBoss 5.1.0.GA uses the jboss-logging-spi.jar for its logging and it can't be removed from the lib folder in its root. I have added jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar in the lib folder of the deployment server, and if I remove it, ClassNotFoundExceptions are being thrown. So I'm now in a fix. I can't remove either of them, and if I don't remove any, then this NoSuchMethodError occurs. Please help me find a solution to this.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You can try: `-verbose:class` and check your managed server's logs to check if the class is being loaded properly.

An efficient way to confirm which intrusive jar might be getting loaded is by running a `whereis.jsp` within the same `webcontext` (i.e., `JVM` instance) of this app.

**whereis.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.URL" %>
<%
Class cls = org.jboss.logging.Logger.class;
ProtectionDomain pDomain = cls.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cSource = pDomain.getCodeSource();
URL loc = cSource.getLocation();
out.println(loc);
// it should print something like "c:/jars/MyJar.jar"
%>
```

Also refer these links, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846184/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-getmessagelogger) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084181/logger-problems-with-hibernate-4-on-jboss-5-1) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886682/hibernate4-on-jboss-eap-5-1-2-logging-error)

The issue can be resolved using the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
   <exclusions>
     <module name="org.javassist" />
     <module name="org.slf4j" />
     <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
   </exclusions>

 <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="logging" />
 </exclude-subsystems>
```

Which can be created under `WEB-INF`. You should also put your `log4j.jar in WEB-INF/lib` or whatever.

Comment: These are all standard responses to the question, which I had already gone through as I said. So thanks for the response, but I'm afraid they did not work in my case.